# IntelliJ structural search generics

Tags: java, intellij-idea, structural-search

Maybe I do not understand IntelliJs structural search not.

I want to find all occurences which match the following example pattern:

```
Map<String, String> mapper = new HashMap<>()
```

My not working approach was

```
Map<$a$,$b$> $c$ = new HashMap<>()
```

Does structural search find it and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a pattern like the following works for me:

```
$map$<$a$,$b$> $c$ = new $hashmap$<>();
```

$map$ text/regexp: `java\.util\.Map`
$hashmap$ text/regexp: `java\.util\.HashMap`

I'm not sure why your pattern didn't work. It is probably a bug.

Comment: Better than nothing and seems to be a good work-around. Difficult for me is that I can not filter on "MAP" as type before the generics. :-|

Comment: How do you mean? My query filters on java.util.Map (Edit Variables and define text/regexp as `java\.util\.Map`).

Comment: Did not saw the possibility to add a regular expression to value of variable. Now it works for me. Thank you